# What can a RAT (Remote Access Trojan) do?

Tags: rat

I have been wondering, if I get infected with a RAT, what can the hacker do to my computer? What will he/she have access to, and what can they do with my computer?

Comment: It is really going to depend on the specific RAT that is used. You can assume that they could access everything and be able to do anything to your machine. Can you narrow down your question?

Comment: If the RAT has a static set of features and doesn't include updating itself, or downloading and executing arbitrary code/binaries then it can only do what its features are. However if it can download aribtrary code then it can do everything your machine can do or can be taught to do.

Comment: Are you asking what a RAT can do, or what the attacker behind it will most likely command it to do? While the answer remain broad, I recommend you to take a look at this [very nice diagram published on KrebsOnSecurity blog](http://krebsonsecurity.com/2012/10/the-scrap-value-of-a-hacked-pc-revisited/) which summarize what value your home PC may have for an attacker and what use he may find for it.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [infosecinstitute.com](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/remote-access-tool/):

> when used for malicious purposes, they are known as a Remote Access Trojan (RAT). They can be used by a malicious user to control the system without the knowledge of the victim. **Most of the popular RATs are capable of performing key logging, screen and camera capture, file access, code execution, registry management, password sniffing etc.**

Since there are many varieties of RAT's, I suggest you start by reading the article I quoted and later if more information is needed a simple Google search will return a lot of information/research's that are relevant.